# How to sum multiple values (integer) from one column to descriptions (character) values in another column?

Tags: sql

I am working on a query with race/ethnicity values in two different forms.

Race_ID field/column (integer) and Race (character) in Race Table has 18 values.

The picture shows the race_ID and race field:

[image: The picture shows the race_ID and race field]

I am trying to combined multiple race_ids into one value of race columns.
For eg: adding 7,8,9,11 to Southeast Asian.

I have tried SUM CASE When and it did not work here. I would greatly appreciate help here.

```
    select Count(*), Race_ID,

(case when RACE_ID in ('7', '8', '9', '11') then 'Southeast Asian'
when RACE_ID in ('4','5', '6') then 'East Asian'
when RACE_ID in ('15', '16', '17') then 'Pacific Islander'
when RACE_ID = '1' then 'White'
when RACE_ID = '2' then 'Hispanic'
when RACE_ID= '3' then 'Black'
when RACE_ID = '10' then 'Filipino'
when RACE_ID = '12' then 'Native American'
when RACE_ID= '13' then 'Middle Eastern'
when RACE_ID= '14' then 'Asian East Indian'
when RACE_ID= '18' then 'Unknown'
when RACE_ID= '19' then 'Other'
                                       
end ) as Race

from Race_table
group by RACE_ID, Race
order by RACE_ID
```

If anyone is able to figure out, your thoughts will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server <> SQLite. Please tag only one database.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. Is this picture your sample data or the results you want to get? Please provide sample data and desired results as two separated tables.

Comment: I assume the picture is what's in Race_table - can you provide what you want your output to be?  I suspect that it's not really clear in your mind what you're looking for.

Comment: Please have concise questions, with detailed information in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select Count(*),
       sum(case when RACE_ID in ('7', '8', '9', '11') then 1 else 0 end) as Southeast_Asian,
       sum(case when when RACE_ID in ('4','5', '6') then 1 else 0 end) as East_Asian,
       . . .
from Race_table;
```

If you actually want a separate row for each race, then:

```
select Count(*),
       (case when RACE_ID in ('7', '8', '9', '11') then 'Southeast Asian'
             when RACE_ID in ('4','5', '6') then 'East Asian'
             when RACE_ID in ('15', '16', '17') then 'Pacific Islander'
             when RACE_ID = '1' then 'White'
             when RACE_ID = '2' then 'Hispanic'
             when RACE_ID = '3' then 'Black'
             when RACE_ID = '10' then 'Filipino'
             when RACE_ID = '12' then 'Native American'
             when RACE_ID = '13' then 'Middle Eastern'
             when RACE_ID = '14' then 'Asian East Indian'
             when RACE_ID = '18' then 'Unknown'
             when RACE_ID = '19' then 'Other'                                               
        end ) as Race
from Race_table
group by Race
order by min(RACE_ID);
```

Not all databases allow you to aggregate by a column alias.  In those databases, you can repeat the `case` expression.